# Laravel models, database and pivot tables question

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, model, pivot-table

Hello I am working with Laravel,
I have to create two simple models, let's say Stores and Books.
Stores can have one or multiple Books and Books can belong to many Stores.
Of course I will use a many to many relationship, with a pivot table.

Books the can have different prices depending the store.

I think a separate table can only complicate things, in my mind the pivot table associating books and stores should have a price column, but pivot tables only contains store_id and book_id.

Should I create a book_prices and associate it with books and to stores? What is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free and able to set other attributes on your pivot table. You can read more about it in the docs.
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

You have to define the relationship accordingly, the following should clarify how this works. In this example you use the many-to-many relationship and add the price column to every retrieved pivot model.

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class)
        ->withPivot('price')
}
```

For example, you are able to access the pivot column in a loop like this

```
foreach ($shop->books as $book)
{
    echo $book->pivot->price;
}
```

Comment: You were the second to respond, but your answer was slightly more complete, thanks.

Comment: Should I utilize the same withPivot method for the reverse of the relationship on the Book model?

Comment: Normally yes, but it is only needed if you are gonna access the pivot column. Otherwise you could skip it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define additional columns for your pivot table in the migration for the pivot table, and then when defining the relationship use `withPivot` to define the additional columns so they come through in the model:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany(Book::class)->withPivot('price');
```

(Adapted from the Laravel documentation, see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the complexity of your case, but yes, you have two options for it. Let's say that the pivot table is called as `book_store`:

- Directly adds `price` column to `book_store`. This is obviously the simpler option. The drawbacks are:

  - The history of the price changes isn't logged. You'll have to create another table for logging if you want to keep this history information.
  - Changes made to `price` will directly change the price of the related `book_store` record. Meaning that a price is being updated "live" e.g users cannot update the price now but "publish" it some time later just like [this example in the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#advanced-has-one-of-many-relationships).
- Create a new, different table to store the price. This may seems relatively more complex, but it may also be more future-proof.

  - Basically, you get 2 things that you miss in the first option above.
  - Don't think too much about `book_store` being a pivot table. One way to see it is like this: `book_store` IS a pivot table from `books` and `stores` tables viewpoints, but it's also just a normal SQL table which could relate to any other tables using any kind of relationships.
  - If you want to implement this, make sure to create a primary-key in the `book_store` table.

Alast, it all depends on what you need. Feel free to ask if you need more insight about this. I hope this helps.